# NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT crashed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

As title said, My app crashed on client side and get reported via Parse crashes report but I just can't reproduce it on my side.

Everything working just fine on both simulator and real device also downloaded app from [app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eminer/id986395501?mt=8) working flawlessly. But I keep getting crash report until today.

[image]

Here's the code for get timezone as integer

```
 static var timezone: Int {
     get {
        return Int(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT/3600) ?? 0
     }
 }
```

It shouldn't be any problem there but crash log end at that line or maybe I just missing something there. Please advice if someone hit this before. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it crashes in Pacific timezone when you cast it to Int. in my case the following fixed the problem

let time = UInt32(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 + NSTimeInterval(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT))

Comment: What closest city (via Date & Time setting) you found it crash?